# Need to send a HTTP request in Python that'll authenticate with Google Accounts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, oauth

I have an app which amounts to a Python script, running on the user's phone, and a JS client, running in the user's browser. The Python script sends messages to App Engine as HTTP requests. The server then pushes the messages to the JS client.

The problem is authentication: The server can easily use Google Accounts to authenticate anything coming from the JS client as being sent by a particular user, but I do not know how to get the Python script to make HTTP requests which will also authenticate.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are looking for two-legged Oauth to make requests from the phone which identify as the legitimate user. OAuth requests are "spoof-proof" unless a bad guy makes unauthorized use of a request token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its homepage, [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) has support for Google Account authentication, maybe that may help you?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use OAUth to authenticate with Google, then use the OAuth token to ensure the messages are legitimate?